# proper android activity flow?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to wrap my head around what proper activity flow convention is.

I currently have:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //do stuff
        //clicklisteners setup etc
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
        //putExtras
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}  

public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //getExtras
        //objectA state lives here
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

If the user presses back when on the ExampleActivity view, and then clicks another listener that takes them to ExampleActivity, I want to be able to access "objectA" state again. How do I implement this? I am not understanding onResume or onRestart...

are these the methods to call? or is there a better convention to navigate the app activities?

Answer (score 1):

Android has a mechanism for having an activity pass results back to the prior activity that started it.  The documentation for that is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities).

Basically, you use [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) to start the second activity, the second activity uses [setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int)) to set results, and the first activity receives those results in the [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) callback when the second activity finishes.

Comment: seems I dont have enough "points to upvote". Thanks. so I pass intent then getIntent() on the callback?

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer as correct (which helps me because I get credit for it.)

Comment: The intent that you passed to setResult(int, Intent) becomes available as the last parameter to the onActivityResult() callback.

Answer (score 0):

If the user presses back when on the ExampleActivity view, the ExampleActivity is dead and user is back in the MainActivity, which calls "onResume".
When your are back from activity1 to activity2, activity2's onResume method is called.
With that being said, after the user closed ExampleActivity objectA is destroyed.

Comment: good to know. I was understanding it as once onCreate is called, the activity is out of focus but still and object.